# Getting an active connection on a Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I get the connection parameters for my HTTP call using the code that follows below.

It works on my test phones and emulators.  However for some people (possibly just 9700 users, but I can't guarantee it) it causes `"Failed to transmit"` errors even when they have an otherwise working 3G/wifi connection.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  private String getConnectionParameters()
  {
    String strCP = null;        

    int coverageStatus = CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus();

    if((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)
    {
      // Carrier coverage
      String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
      if(carrierUid == null) 
      {
        String wap2 = getWAP2ServiceRecord();

        if (wap2 != null)
        {
          // Try using WAP2
          strCP = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+wap2;  
        }
        else
        {
          // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS or WAP2.  So use the carrier's TCP network
          strCP = ";deviceside=true";
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS request
        strCP = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
      }
    }
    else if((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS)
    {
      // MDS coverage found
      strCP = ";deviceside=false";
    }
    else if((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) && RadioInfo.areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN))
    {
      // Device is connected via Wifi
      strCP = ";interface=wifi";
    }
    else if(coverageStatus == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
    {
      // There is no available connection
      strCP = "";
    }
    else
    {
      // no other options found, assuming device
      strCP = ";deviceside=true";
    }

    return strCP;
  }

  private String getCarrierBIBSUid()
  {
    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();

    for(int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    {
      if(records[i].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp"))
      {
        if(records[i].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0)
        {
          return records[i].getUid();
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  private String getWAP2ServiceRecord()
  {
    ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();

    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    {
      String cid = records[i].getCid().toLowerCase();
      String uid = records[i].getUid().toLowerCase();

      if ((cid.indexOf("wptcp") != -1) && (uid.indexOf("wifi") == -1) && (uid.indexOf("mms") == -1))
      {
        return records[i].getUid();
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with my connection class before I found the [Versatile Monkey connection code](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/HttpConnectionFactory.java)

My problem was with BIS connections, you need to loop and try each connection.  Not sure if it's a carrier thing, or a CDMA vs GSM thing.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to try each connection, but that does look very useful, thank you!

Comment: Could also be APN settings on the device. TCP might say it works... but if the user doesn't have APN settings :(  Been bit by this a couple times too!

Comment: I'll check that out.  The problem seems to be only on Bold 9700 on T-Mobile, which is pretty weird.